# Jquery Cycle Plugin: How do you pause a slideshow on load

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle

I I want to load a Jquery Cycle slideshow and after loading pause until the user clicks the Play button. I am new to Jquery so could you give me a detailed explanation and possibly example code. You can see my slideshow @ www.sessomsphotographics.com

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can send the string `'pause'` to the cycle plugin to pause it, and then send in `'resume'` to resume it.

```
// start cycle with default options
$('#rotator').cycle();

// immediately pause it
$('#rotator').cycle('pause');

// when the play button is clicked, resume
$('#play-button').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#rotator').cycle('resume');
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but I have to double click the play link to start the slide show  which is coded to toggle from play to pause. below is the code I tried.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.slideshow').cycle({
  fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 4000,
        speed: 500,
  delay: 0,        
  pager: '#pager',  
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
  pause: 1,
  fit: 1
 });
 $('#playControl').click(function () {
  
  $('#playControl').toggle(
  function() {
   $('.slideshow').cycle('pause');
   $(this).text('Play');      
  }),
  
  function() {
   $('.slideshow').cycle('resume'); 
   $(this).text('Pause');
  }
 });
 });

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the cycle options so that it never starts in auto-advance mode.  Download a copy of jquery.cycle.all.2.72.js (or some variant) and do a search within for "$.fn.cycle.defaults = {".  Set "timeout" (the second option) to zero.

Answer (score 1):

That works great, I ended up using this :

```
// Cycle
$('ul#div_cycle').cycle({
    next:    '#next',
    prev:    '#prev', 
    fx:     'scrollHorz', 
    timeout: 2000, 
    delay:  -3500,
    pause: 1
});

// Pause cycle
$('ul#div_cycle').cycle('pause');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send it the 'pause' message on ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                     
    $('.slideshow').cycle('pause'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks This also worked. I am still having a bit of a problem. See my comments above.